# Running migrations on Heroku and Local

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've tried to run python manage.py migrate on my local environment and getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: travel_userprofile
```

I also tried to run heroku run python manage.py migrate and getting a seperate error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "travel_place_e8701ad4" already exists
```

I've been scratching my head all day and haven't found a solution. Posting here to see if anyone can help out. I'm so close to seeing my app live.

Comment: can you reset the database ?

Comment: Just tried that on my local and still getting the same error. So strange.

Comment: try to going to a previous migration.

Comment: how do you go about doing that?

Comment: ./manage.py migrate --list, then  ./manage.py migrate your_app migration_number (e.g ./manage.py migrate my_app 0001)

Comment: I think you need to revise your migration files maually. Did you have deleted migration file(s) manually ??

Comment: Yes, I have, I've done what levi has said and rolled back to a prev migration which works, but when i run manage.py migrate again it just brings all the migrations back and throws the same error.